# How to create a method inside of the blade file on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I recently started learning Laravel and I am still trying to figure it out. So, please bear in mind this before judging me :)

I am trying to find a way to rewrite this:

```
<a href="{{ url('clients/'. $campaign->client_id) }}">{{ App\Client::find($campaign->client_id)->name }}</a>
```

with a method, so I wouldn't have to do `Client::find()` inside of the view.

I tried doing this:

```
private function getClientName($id)
{
    $clientName = Client::find($id)->name;
    return view('campaigns.index', compact('clientName'));
}
```

... in the controller and called the method inside of the view, but it didn't work, and I can't think of anything else right now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create helper files using composer.  In order to make it work, you will need to autoload it within your composer.json file.  You will need to add the "files" along with a path to the helper file you've created.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "helpers/general.php"
    ]
},
```

Once you've done this, you should be able to add a regular function to your helper file.  It might look something like this.

```
<?php 

function getClientName($id){
    // Add code to get client name
}
```

You could then access from your blade like this.

```
<a href="{{ url('clients/'. $campaign->client_id) }}">{{ getClientName($campaign->client_id) }}</a>
```

What I've suggested should work, but the more Laravel way of doing it would be to properly build your relationship so you can do something like the following.

```
<a href="{{ url('clients/'. $campaign->client->id) }}">{{ $campaign->client->name }}</a>
```

I'd need to see your database structure in order to suggest which type of relationship you'd need, but you should be able to find what you're looking for in the documentation.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships.

Edit:  Since you seem to have client_id in your campaign table, that means your campaign likely "BelongsTo" a client.  A client on the other hand has "HasMany" campaigns.  This terminology might help you with the documentation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: `<a href="{{ url('clients/'. $campaign->client->id) }}">{{ $campaign->client->name }}</a>`

My Campaign model has a  `public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }`

Comment: I already did the relationship thing for both Client and Campaign, and i tried many times before posting this here, but I can't understand why it doesn't work properly... I think I am losing my mind! This is the error I get: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name`

Comment: Oohhh, i finally realised why it didn't work!!!!! I was doing this: `$campaign->client()->name` instead of `$campaign->client->name`!!! Thanks a million! This is the solution with Eloquent Relationships `<a href="{{ url('clients/'. $campaign->client->id) }}">{{ $campaign->client->name }}</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Use your controller to do that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use App\Client;

class Clients extends Controller 
{
    public function index() 
    {
       // You must have campaign here somehow
       $campaign = whateverYouNeed();

       // Then find the client and get the name 
       $clientName = Client::find($campaign->client_id)->name;

       // And pass them both to your view
       return view('clients', compact('campaign', 'clientName'))
    }
}
```

Then in your blade:

```
<a href="{{ url('clients/'. $campaign->client_id) }}">{{ $clientName }}</a>
```

Another good way of doing this in Laravel is to use relationships:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Campaign extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

Then you just have to use them in your blade:

```
<a href="{{ url('clients/'. $campaign->client_id) }}">{{ $campaign->client->name }}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The thing is that I can't pass the $id as a parameter on index(). The $id is actually the client_id, which I don't know until I get inside the view here `$campaign->client_id`

Comment: But you passed the campaign to your view via controller, right? So you have acces to it. Edited to show how.

Comment: @MattE.What do you mean you don't know the client_id until you get inside the view? How is this value determined?

Comment: @Birdman: in controller's index() method, i get all the campaigns like this `$campaigns = Campaign::all();`, then inside of the view, i loop them with a foreach. so, the cliend_id is determined by each iteration of the campaigns.